# what is Sun VM's equivalent option to IBM VM's -Xcheck:jni:alwayscopy?

Tags: java, jvm, sun

what is Sun VM's equivalent option to IBM VM's -Xcheck:jni:alwayscopy ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a reference to that option in the IBM JVM?  I can see a [description of -Xcheck:jni](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1450.html) on its own, but the only reference on the entire internet to "-Xcheck:jni:alwayscopy" is this post of yours.  Are there any documents on it, and failing that, what does it do that you'd like the Sun JVM to replicate?

In any case, as per [this list of Sun JVM options](http://blogs.oracle.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html), you've been able to pass the `-Xcheck:jni` flag, in order to perform additional checks on JNI functions, since 1.3.1.  This achieves the same thing as the same flag in IBM's VM.

Are you sure that the `alwayscopy` part of the argument is actually being honoured by the IBM JVM, and not just silently ignored to act as if you typed `-Xcheck:jni`?

Comment: IBM JDK does supports this option. this instructs certain JNI [Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements @ http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314 ]functions to always return a copy of the data. This is what the doc says "Since the returned array may be a copy of the Java array, changes made to the returned array will not necessarily be reflected in the original array until Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements() is called.". By default, the same primitive array is returned, but using this option, instructs the VM to always return a copy of the array element.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a IBM "`check:jni:`*`alwayscopy`*" option.
The IBM Developer Kit and Runtime Environment, Java 2 Technology Edition, Version 1.4.2, does mention a:

"[`-Xcheck:jni`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1450.html#id1450)" option which causes a set of wrappers around the actual JNI functions to be activated.

But it is quite similar to the option check:jni [introduced in the JRE1.3 and 1.3](http://java.sun.com/developer/TechTips/2000/tt0801.html) (see also [JNI design](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/design.html), and [JNI tips](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/jni-tips.html))

```
java -classic -cp . -Xcheck:jni Max
```

(although the JRE1.6 might also [require the "`-XX:+RestoreMXCSROnJNICalls`" option](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6539718) in certain condition)